# Why isn't my Normal Map visible after baking&applying texture?

Tags: mesh, baking, normal-map

Here's my .blend file for reference:
[AllMight Blend File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByTN_g1DxQR5TXdIelhfVEJKTnc)

I have two meshes. One Low Poly mesh in layer one, another high poly in layer 2. I believe I've followed the correct steps for baking and applying a normal map to the low poly mesh, but it doesn't even seem to appear in render mode. And I don't think it looks right in texture mode either.

If someone could take a look at my file and settings for baking/applying the normal map UV that would be tremendously helpful.

P.S. There's a sun lamp in layer 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you applied the texture to the silver material. I can see the effect on the belt buckle. Have you tried applying the normal texture to the rest of the materials?

Comment: Oh my gosh, I'm going to check this right now.. I had no idea you had to go through and bake your texture to every material you have.

Comment: That was definitely the issue! Now my problem is that the normal map looks really dark on my low poly mesh. Not at all like the high poly mesh.

Comment: I didn't check your normals. maybe they're inverted? That would make the lighting act funny. Glad I could help!

Comment: Thanks, but normals definitely aren't inverted. I have backface culling selected to make sure I never do that lol. Perhaps I just need to try the baking process again with different settings. I did it with a margin of 30px and a distance of 1.000 last time.

Comment: I found out what went wrong. I forgot to select "Normal Map" under "Image Sampling" in the Texture options.